# Почему при редиректе дописывает в get параметр seo_url Opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.0

Подскажите почему при редиректе добавляет get параметр? Записал в таблицу url_redirect старый и новый url. 
grunt-akriloviy-silikonoviy-kale-silastar -> gruntovki/brend-kale

Но при редиректе выдает - gruntovki/brend-kale/&brend=brend-kale

Если прописать в таблице - 
grunt-akriloviy-silikonoviy-kale-silastar -> index.php?route=product/category/filter&path=575&brend=brend-kale

то возвращает - gruntovki/

Подскажите как можно это поправить?

Comment: Opencart версии 2.0.3

Comment: Потому, что это скорее всего это переход по фильтру, который обрабатывает GET запрос.

Comment: уже разобрался...Спасибо!